# How to integrate Spring Security with Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-batch

I want to create a secured web application where users can launch Spring Batch jobs. I want to keep track about who launched which job and thus I have to associate a `JobInstance` (or a `JobExecution`?) with a user. I additionally want to query for `JobExecution`s that were started by a particular user. This does not seem to be a common use case since I could not find a solution for this in the reference guide.

Do I have to write my own implementations for the persistence layer of Spring Batch? This seems to be much overhead for just adding a field to a table. Does anybody know a simple solution?

Comment: Why don't rely on `JobParameters`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/domain.html#domainJobParameters, http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html#metaDataSchemaOverview?

Comment: You mean that I shall always inject the current (or launching) user into the parameters? How can I query for `JobExecutions` based on the 'user-parameter' when I use this approach?

Comment: Would it be suitable to extend the default implementations and to add methods that execute these queries?

Comment: As you fish. But seems form me `JdbcJobInstanceDao` has everything what you need.

Comment: I don't think so. For example I have the user and a timestamp as the identifying parameters of each job. I can not search for a `JobInstance` when the timestamp is unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Artem Bilan suggested I inject the current user into the `JobParameters`. I have written a simple service class that provides a method that queries for the execution ids of a given user:

```
@Service
public class JobService {

    private static final String FIND_EXECUTIONS = "SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM batch_job_execution_params WHERE KEY_NAME = 'user' AND STRING_VAL = ? ORDER BY JOB_EXECUTION_ID DESC";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Long> findJobExecutionIdsByUser(String username) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(FIND_EXECUTIONS, Long.class, username);
    }

}
```

With this list I am able to get the `JobExecution`s from the default `JobExplorer` like this:

```
final List<Long> executionIds = jobService.findJobExecutionIdsByUser("user");
final List<JobExecution> executions = new ArrayList<>();

for (Long executionId : executionIds) {
    final JobExecution execution = explorer.getJobExecution(executionId);

    if (execution != null) {
        executions.add(execution);
    }
}
```